# Using %w with a string from an object

Tags: ruby, arrays

I want to use the %w function to convert a string to an array, however the string is coming from an object

So I'd like to implement something like this:

```
%w(@object.string)
or
%w(#{@object.string})
```

Neither of which works.

Is this possible?

Comment: Use `#split` method... `%W` is for a set of strings which are separated by whitespace, you can turn them into an array. if you have `%w( foo bar )` but not for `%w( "foo bar" )`. `%w( "foo bar" )` wiill give you `["foo bar" ]`. But I am sure you want `["foo", "bar" ]`

Comment: Thanks! the split method is the perfect alternative. Feel free to add it as an answer and I will accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`#split`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/String.html#method-i-split) method... `%W/%w` is for a set of *strings* which are separated by **whitespace**, you can turn them into an **array**. If you have `%w( foo bar )` but not for `%w( "foo bar" )`. `%w( "foo bar" )` will give you `["foo bar" ]`. But I am sure you want `["foo", "bar" ]`.

Comment: Thanks! I hadn't considered using .split

Answer (score 1):

You can just use `[@object.string]` or `Array[@object.string]`

**Dangerous solution**

There is also option with eval (but everybody knows that eval is evil).
`eval("%w(#{@object.string}")`.
I still think you should be just using Array, Enumerable and String methods instead of this.

Comment: %w will split on spaces, I think your top solution would create ["Value of String"]? I'm looking for ["Value", "of", "string"]. @Arup has answered with the .split method, which I think is the best solution. I'm marking your answer up for the eval solution as it is the literal answer to my question (albiet not good) - thanks

Comment: `eval` isn't evil. Using `eval` with unsecured input data is evil.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from using split you can do it that way implementing the to_s method and using the %W but you could implement a to_a method right away also.

```
class Myobject
  attr_reader :my_attr1, :my_attr2

  def initialize(my_attr1, my_attr2)
    @my_attr1 = my_attr1
    @my_attr2 = my_attr2
  end

  def to_s
    "#{my_attr1} #{my_attr2}"
  end

  def to_a
    # [my_attr1, my_attr2]
    self.split
  end

end

myobject = Myobject.new('string1', 'string2')
p myobject.to_a # ["string1", "string2"]
p myobject.to_s #"string1 string2"
p %W(#{myobject.to_s}) #["string1 string2"]
```

Comment: I'm not sure this does what the OP asked, which was basically how to split the string. Trying to use `%w` or `%W` just showed he was on the wrong path.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible with `%w()` but it is possible with `%W():`

```
  x = "abc"  # => "abc"
  %w( x )    # => ["x"]
  %w( #{x} ) # => ["\#{x}"]
  %W( #{x} ) # => ["abc"]
```

Comment: This doesn't accomplish a split, it only creates an array using that string. Using a more useful test string: `X = 'abc def'`, when interpolated this is the result: `%W[#{X}] # => ["abc def"]`